# Is it possible to write a report to send a weekly digest of people who have filled in a webform survey

Tags: civireport

I would like to send a report once a week to a client with everyone who has filled in a survey in the last week and has a particular tag.

IN civireport I can see I can filter by activity subject but the field activity date only has last 12 months, custom date, null, not null. I would like "last 7 days".

Also I can only see group not tag. I'm wondering if civireport can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the *Activity Details Report*? It has a filter on activity data *Last Seven Days including today*. See:

[image: Activity Details Report]

In order to filter on a tag, you can create a smart group that contains all the contacts with the tag. That gives you the option to use the Group filter.